# Codeigniter: Make Trigger Update After Insert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have Table With Structure:

#### tb_berita

[image: tb_berita]

#### tb_kategori

[image]

#### nama_kategori in tb_kategori

[image: nama_kategori]

I have a trigger named `updateJumlahBerita` have a function to

```
<p>**Update jumlah_berita + 1 In tb_kategori After Insert From tb_berita Where id_kategori(from tb_berita)=id_kategori(from tb_kategori)** :
```

```
    CREATE TRIGGER updateJumlahBerita AFTER INSERT ON tb_berita 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
       UPDATE tb_kategori 
        SET jumlah_berita = jumlah_berita + 1 
        WHERE id_kategori = id_kategori; 
    END;
```

But the problem is, After i'm Insert Berita With kategori( let's say **sport**) All kategori +1 , but i want only **SPORT**to +1.

can you help me with this ?

Thank's

Comment: for dynamic criteria, use query and update record instead of trigger.

Comment: In an after insert  trigger I would expect to see reference to NEW. values 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.

In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @P.Salmon In my trigger what i can change to `NEW` ?`WHERE id_kategori=NEW.id_kategori` like this ?

Comment: That's correct according my understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @P.Salmon It's Works after add `NEW`, Thanks.